# conduct instead of execute

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "conduct" instead of "execute" at below sentence. Or are there any better alternatives for execute?

> SQL injection vulnerabilities in in Joomla allow remote attackers to
> execute arbitrary SQL commands.

EDIT:
Which one is more appropriate if you compare with execute:

> SQL injection vulnerabilities in in Joomla allow remote attackers to
> **run** arbitrary SQL commands.
>
> SQL injection vulnerabilities in in Joomla allow remote attackers to
> **carry out** arbitrary SQL commands.
>
> SQL injection vulnerabilities in in Joomla allow remote attackers to
> **perform** arbitrary SQL commands.

Comment: Commands are **executed**, not **conducted**, AFAIK.

Comment: You can **run** or **execute** code, but not conduct code...

Comment: No.  No more than you'd "conduct" a prisoner with a firing squad.

Comment: I think this question has had a long enough innings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research; question answered in comments.

Answer (score 1):

"SQL injection vulnerabilities in in Joomla allow remote attackers to execute arbitrary SQL commands."

Q: Can I use "conduct" instead of "execute" at below sentence. Or are there any better alternatives for execute?

A:  For background - JOOMLA! - Is an open source Web based software platform for website creators. It is financed or sponsored by OpenSource Matters!, a non-profit organization based in New York City, NY (www.joomla.org). www.breitbart.com also gives a good write up on JOOMLA! and its' parent company. The acronym "SQL" stands for "Structured Query Language," - a computer programming  language used for database management (www.dictionary.com).

Computer technology, or Information Systems Technology (IT) has grown and expanded since the birth of computer technology from the mid 20th century to today.  Presently, it is considered a well respected and established technical field of Engineering.

It is, therefore, best to refer you to, like for the United States, the IEEE Standard Glossary of Software Engineering Technology, as English words and terms applied to Information Technology have additional meaning, application, and use not found in a standard dictionary; ie., such as Merriam-Webster, or an Oxford dictionary.

Boston, MA (USA) - Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) has this glossary posted as a .pdf issued by the U.S. Government [.pdf file at http://www.mit.jyu.fi/ope/kurssit/TIES462/Materiaalit/IEEE_SoftwareEngGlossary.pdf] downloadable for free.

Commonly referred to as STS 610.12-1990 under its' glossary of computer terminology, this technical reference lists a definition for  "execute" as: "To carry out an instruction, process, or computer program."

"Conduct" is not listed as a computer / Information technology word, so I would refrain from using it in Information technology technical writing.

Why? Since the subject content of the statement sentence you provided is related specifically and directly to an Information Technology system process, it would be prudent to advise you use reach first for the appropriate terminology of "execute" in an Information Technology approved glossary of terms and advise you to use that to answer your question.

Professionals, which now includes Information Technology, use technical writing that might be outside the scope of this website.  For the field for which technical writing on or about, it is prudent for you to have this type of glossary close by when conducting technical English writing just as in the same manner as Medical Doctors do, when publishing English papers for Journals, etc., or those in the Medical profession use.  They, too, have their own separate, but similar Medical reference dictionary.

I hope this helps.

Lastly, for the past 20 years, Ms. Vangie Beal, an expert in electronic commerce and Internet Information Technology, has served as Managing Editor of Webopedia [I'm almost hesitant to refer you to it, as it sounds too much like "Wikipedia" and many, many institutes of higher learning strongly caution Students in Academia not to use or cite Wikipedia, and for good reason. However, Webopedia is a trusted website that serves to solely keep a much more updated glossary of Information Technology acronyms and words, so you have the authorative U.S. Government publication and a way to cross check with an online website that is more up to date.  See: - https://www.webopedia.com/TERM  - You can either enter in the term to get the definition or search the English term by alphabetical order.